# Diagonal abline() in qplot (R)

Tags: r, plot

I have a Q-Q plot and I want to add a diagonal line from the bottom left to top right using `geom_abline()`, but I can't do it. I tried experimenting with adding different values to `slope` and `intercept`, but I can't quite figure out how they work.

```
qqplot1 <- qplot(sample = TotalOutl$IntenMax, size=I(0.2))
qqplot1 + geom_abline()
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

This is the first 100 values (out of 69971) from the dataset for the recreation:

```
> head(TotalOutl$PitchSlope,100)
[1] 206.420 347.554 253.465 142.582 66.740 452.779 378.993 175.202 67.232 310.163 344.753
[12] 152.371 32.810 597.210 283.097 224.434 243.165 114.934 128.275 83.683 165.573 14.770
[23] 844.842 175.110 119.188 581.248 338.125 88.890 84.591 13.427 150.226 267.856 287.526
[34] 443.087 537.364 188.809 176.559 349.574 154.171 71.194 126.877 203.582 66.150 82.363
[45] 341.778 96.092 514.442 471.534 871.443 139.505 468.785 227.930 350.540 284.449 384.741
[56] 373.317 326.618 172.510 470.861 946.482 328.471 193.219 122.543 87.408 174.261 221.541
[67] 233.468 455.817 409.254 106.121 316.740 196.465 300.801 275.126 122.865 135.804 191.313
[78] 139.063 347.188 344.517 268.236 357.009 332.925 145.890 92.050 195.758 269.396 366.989
[89] 274.478 156.439 875.086 191.737 67.716 135.111 457.542 199.416 85.328 108.091 182.435
[100] 298.021
```

Comment: @dgr379 Sorry my bad , geom_abline with slope or intercept option. geom_point() + geom_abline(intercept=20) or ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + geom_abline(slope=5) . My sincere apologies , my mind went to football ground

Comment: Can you please supply the data that we can replicate your plot? Or make an example with self created data.

Comment: @Benjamin Schlegel I did :)

Comment: PKumar The problem is even when I do qqplot1+geom_abline(slope=100), the line shows up somewhere in the middle almost vertical and I don't know how to turn it around as much as I tried adjusting intercept as well)

Comment: Pasting the results of `dput(head(TotalOutl$PitchSlope,100))` rather than just `head(TotalOutl$PitchSlope,100)` would make it easier for others to reproduce.

Comment: @John Coleman Sorry, I didn't know about this one. Now I do. Thank you for mentioning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a slicker way, but you can use `ggplot_build` to extract the x and y limits and then manually compute the slope and intercept. The following illustrates this with random data:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(1000)
qqplot1 <- qplot(sample = x,size=I(0.2))
xlims <- ggplot_build(qqplot1)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.range
ylims <- ggplot_build(qqplot1)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$y.range
rise <- ylims[2]-ylims[1]
run <- xlims[2]-xlims[1]
m <- rise/run
b <- ylims[1] - m*xlims[1]
qqplot1 + geom_abline(slope = m, intercept = b)
```

Output:

[image]